# macOS Big Sur - screen sharing back to Mac mini over Internet

Tags: macos

Now that "Back to my Mac" is gone, is there any way to connect back to a Mac mini over Internet using Screen Sharing.

Problem is that I have to be physically at my Mac mini to accept incoming Screen Sharing request, even it is the same Apple ID user logged in on both?

Answer (score 1):

Logging in by host name instead of AppleID will not trigger the screen sharing request that requires local user input.

Comment: Thanks but I does not work over public Internet?

Comment: Logging in by hostname or IP address will work over the public internet if there's no network address translation or firewalls in the way.  Setting up NAT and firewall rules can clear a path for a connection but that will punch holes in network security for what is likely an already quite insecure protocol.  A properly configured virtual private network will secure the communications and allow use of a private network hostname or IP address to connect.  With setting up a secure screen sharing system being rarely easy there's plenty of people willing to hire themselves out to set these up.